# Show Configurable Product in Best sellers

Tags: magento-1.8, sales, reports

Magento does not show up configurable base product in the best sellers. Code is:

```
// Filter only products with visibility catalog,search & catalog
$_visibility = array(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG,
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH
);
$_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addOrderedQty('', '', true, false, false)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $_visibility)
    ->addStoreFilter($_storeId)
    ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($_collection);
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($_collection);
```

How to show configurable products? Also which tables this collection would query?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following code to display the configurable products under the bestseller section.

```
// First make a copy, otherwise the rest of the page might be affected!
$collection = clone $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
// Unset the current products and filter before loading the next.
$collection->clear()->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable')
                   ->load();
```